# Pretty print in Eclipse CDT: unable to look at any variable

Tags: python, qt, eclipse-cdt, pretty-print, kepler

I'm developing a QT based application on ARM, iMX6 device.
Using toolchain from Freescale and Eclipse CDT Kepler, I would like to use pretty printer with GDB.
I followed the tutorial on http://anadoxin.org/blog/node/98 and the setup seems fine (no error while starting GDB).
However when  looking at debug view panel, I'm not able to look at any datatype (not only QT but also int, double etc, the whole panel is blank. Furthermore also writing print variable to gdb Eclipse console doesn't generate a valid output).

I think my setup is fine:

1. GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6 for ARM device
2. Python: Python 2.7.3
3. Eclipse: Kepler
4. KUbuntu 12.04

Is there anyone that can help me understand what is wrong? 
Can I send any command to gdb console in order to understand why pretty printer aren't working fine, and even worse, they corrupt the whole gdb debug view variables?
Any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fixed it.
The problem was that my toolchain for ARM was built without the support for Python in GDB. If you search the web, you will find that there is a flag in the configuration named (--with-python).

Using it and rebuilding gdb, you will be able to use the python scripts available at

[Pretty printers](http://quickgit.kde.org/?p=kdevelop.git&a=tree&h=2276bc198f437a85a1bbfa5cbbd3cb33e6247fc8&hb=5d22a60748bb8069a7e8f7dd0549407d4269e920&f=debuggers/gdb/printers)

Hope this will be helpful for the stackoverflow community.
best regards